# Task.FromResult() vs. Task.Run()

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've come across quite a few situations lately where `async` methods execute synchronously, but return a Task anyway, so they can be awaited, e.g.

```
public virtual Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    Context.Save(user);
    Context.Flush();
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Surely it is better to dispatch the probably-long-running operation to a thread and return the still active task, to genuinely be awaited:

```
public virtual Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Context.Save(user);
        Context.Flush();
    });
}
```

I some suspicion, though, that just spinning off TPL threads isn't the safest practice. Any commentary on these two different patterns?

Comment: When possible, you should call an actual async method, instead of either of those.

Comment: @SLaks In what way is the second one not async (other than not using a new keyword)? (coming from someone who doesn't use async features often)

Comment: @KyleW: It still wastes a thread.  See http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: @SLaks Ok, I get what you're saying.  Better to `await Context.Save(user)` and go from there.  If we assume that Context.Save is 3rd-party and we cannot add async there, what are our options?  It seems like out of the options given in the OP, the first one that blocks the current thread is much worse than the second, which at least shunts it to another thread and allows the current to continue?

Comment: Why are you returning a `Task` in the first place?  Just make the method `void`.

Comment: @KyleW: If you don't have any non-blocking work to do, async is useless to you (unless you want to avoid the UI thread, which is completely irrelevant in ASP.Net)

Comment: @Servy I'm implementing an interface that stipulates the method return `Task`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your method is synchronous you shouldn't return a `Task` to begin with. Just create a traditional synchronous method.

If for some reason that's not possible (for example, you implement some async interface) returning a completed task using `Task.FromResult` or even better in this case `Task.CompletedTask` (added in .NET 4.6) is much better than using `Task.Run` in the implementation:

```
public virtual Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    // ...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If the consumer of your API cares strongly about the `Task`-returning method not running synchronously they can use `Task.Run` themselves to make sure.

You should keep in mind that async methods may have a considerable synchronous part (the part before the first await) even if they do eventually continue asynchronously. **You can't assume async methods return a `Task` immediately anyway.**

Answer (score 27):

`Task.FromResult` doesn't actually creates or runs a task but it just wraps the returned result in a task object. I personally used it in `Unit Tests` where I need to simulate the `Async` methods and Of course I wouldn't want to run actual tasks in Unit tests.

Besides `Task.Run` will actually create a task and run a task on TaskScheduler. It is not recommended to use `Task.Run` when you're doing `Async` programming. Rather use `await` on tasks. See few [do's and don't of Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) by Stephen Cleary.