# Task.Run Vs typical method with Task output

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

Consider:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => Foo());
await t;
void Foo()
{
  Console.WriteLine("hi");
}
```

and :

```
var t2 = Foo2();
await t2;
Task Foo2()
{
  Console.WriteLine("hi2");
  return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Are these two equal in terms of using thread? Both of them run immediately when they're assigned to the `t` variable? if consider `Foo` as long running task, so now what is their behaviour (in terms of using thread)?

Comment: The latter snippet won't compile - did you mean to use `async`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for confusion, i just updated the code

Comment: Related: [Task.FromResult() vs. Task.Run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005397/task-fromresult-vs-task-run).

Comment: The code still won't compile - you still haven't declared `Foo2` as `async`...

Comment: @JonSkeet the code ([revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76543398/3)) does compile and runs successfully ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYLRQU)).

Comment: Ah, whoops - I hadn't noticed the change to return CompletedTask, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var t = Task.Run(() => Foo());
> ```

This line executes the `Foo` on the `ThreadPool`, and returns an incomplete task that represents the completion of the `Foo` execution. If you check the `t.IsCompleted`, before `await`ing the `t`, you'll find it to be `false`.

> ```
> var t2 = Foo2();
> ```

This line executes the `Foo2` on the current thread, and since the `Foo2` is a method with synchronous implementation (albeit with asynchronous signature/contract) it will return an already completed `Task`. If you check the `t2.IsCompleted`, before `await`ing the `t2`, you'll find it to be `true`.

Comment: So in the second code, if it were a long runing task fir exmaple i/o bound task, so the code would execute on the thread pool? Can u plz explain in this situation?

Comment: @pejman no. In the second code the `Foo2` runs on the current thread. It doesn't matter if the `Foo2` is short or long running.